# eclipse - added source .jar overrided by system library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jansi

I tried to add the latest jansi library (1.9) from http://jansi.fusesource.org/ to my eclipse, because the build in library from jansi is not up to date and is missing the "Ansi.ansi().fgBright(Color color)" which was added more than a year ago ...
so i added the new jar in the referenced libraries ...
But the method is still not there ... it is definitely in the newly added jar ... maybe the java system library overrides the new jansi library?

How can I prefer referenced libraries over system libraries?
Anybody knows?

Comment: How/why would the jansi library be part of your system library?

Comment: i have no idea but i can import the library even if i did not add it to the build path ... so where would it come from, if not the system library?

Comment: It may be worthwhile trying to investigate down that path (why is it in the system library, or at least why is it on your default classpath). It's a whole lot easier to maintain/deploy apps when all of your dependencies are part of the app, and don't require any external modifications, like to the system's Java installation

Comment: the problem is, i can't find it in the system library ... but it must be there, because i was coding around with ansi and noticed, there is a "Ansi ansi = new Ansi.ansi()" due to Ansi was red underlined I got the proposal (from eclipse) to 
"import org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi;" ... and i did ... so i googled this and saw, there is a new version with the methods i was looking for ... but i dont know where eclipse has the old jansi library ... so i can't replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems like the source in the systemlib was newer than the downloaded one ...
I just found a solution to my coding problem, but not how to prefer user libraries over system ones. nvm ... it's not neccessary anymore. //closed